# Text aligning in Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I had one problem with centering the image in a carousel (fortunately I found the answer here) and now I got into another problem, aligning the text. More precise, I want the image (it a fixed size image 400x400) to be on the left side with text on the right side. Any suggestions ?

HTML:

```
<!-- Start Carousel -->
    <div id="product-detail carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-img"></div>
            <div class="carousel-text">
              <p class="cat-title pull-right">Mercury</p>
              <p class="cat-icon pull-right">^^^^^</p>
              <p class="caption-text pull-right">Movie buff Tony Chou (Tony Zhou) published in his Vimeo video review with an analysis of the demonstration set of SMS and other text messages in modern cinema.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="..." alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
        ...
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left control-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right control-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>

<!-- End Carousel -->
```

CSS :

```
/*************************
    CAROUSEL
*************************/

.carousel .carousel-inner {
    height: 550px;
    background: #faf9f9;
}

.carousel-control.right,
.carousel-control.left {
    background-image: none;
}

.control-icon {
    color: #393939;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.item {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
.carousel-img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url('../img/jewelery.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.carousel-text .cat-icon {
    text-shadow: none;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.carousel-text .caption-text {
    color: #b7b7b7;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: I think, you can take tow col-md-6 div in item, and first col-md-6 div you can put image and 2nd col-md-6 div you put text.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. I set the carousel text to display inline block and gave it a left of 400px you can study the rest (there's not much else) here;s a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/fpxn1znz/)

```js
// invoke the carousel
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 3000
});

/* SLIDE ON CLICK */

$('.carousel-linked-nav > li > a').click(function () {

    // grab href, remove pound sign, convert to number
    var item = Number($(this).attr('href').substring(1));

    // slide to number -1 (account for zero indexing)
    $('#myCarousel').carousel(item - 1);

    // remove current active class
    $('.carousel-linked-nav .active').removeClass('active');

    // add active class to just clicked on item
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');

    // don't follow the link
    return false;
});

/* AUTOPLAY NAV HIGHLIGHT */

// bind 'slide' function
$('#myCarousel').bind('slide', function () {

    // remove active class
    $('.carousel-linked-nav .active').removeClass('active');

    // get index of currently active item
    var idx = $('#myCarousel .item.active').index();

    // select currently active item and add active class
    $('.carousel-linked-nav li:eq(' + idx + ')').addClass('active');

});
```

```css
.carousel-slide {
    width:100%;
    height:550px;
    background: #faf9f9;
}
.carousel .carousel-inner {
    height: 550px;
    width:900px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background: #faf9f9;
}
.carousel-control.right, .carousel-control.left {
    background-image: none;
}
.control-icon {
    color: #393939;
    text-shadow: none;
}
.item {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
.carousel-text {
    left:400px!important;
    display:inline-block;
}
.carousel-img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    /*    background-image: url('http://rachelgallen.com/images/purpleflowers.jpg');*/
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.carousel-text p.cat-icon {
    text-shadow: none;
    left: 407px;
    position:relative;
    top:30px;
}
.carousel-text p.cat-title {
    text-shadow: none;
    left:380px;
    width:250px;
    position:relative;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.carousel-text p.caption-text {
    top:31px;
    left:420px;
    width:290px;
    position:relative;
    color: #b7b7b7;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-right.control-icon {
    margin-right:-30px;
    width:15px;
    position:absolute;
    color: #393939;
    text-shadow: none;
}
.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-left.control-icon {
    margin-left:-45px;
    width:15px;
    position:absolute;
    color: #393939;
    text-shadow: none;
}
.carousel-linked-nav {
    width: 120px;
    margin-left:40%!important;
    margin-right:40%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-img">
                    <img src="http://rachelgallen.com/images/purpleflowers.jpg" width="400" height="400"></img>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-text">
                    <p class="cat-title pull-right">Mercury</p>
                    <p class="cat-icon pull-right">^^^^^</p>
                    <p class="caption-text">Movie buff Tony Chou (Tony Zhou) published in his Vimeo video review with an analysis of the demonstration set of SMS and other text messages in modern cinema.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-img">
                    <img src="http://rachelgallen.com/images/daisies.jpg" width="400" height="400"></img>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-text">
                    <p class="cat-title pull-right">Venus</p>
                    <p class="cat-icon pull-right">^^^^^</p>
                    <p class="caption-text">Aren't these flowers lovely? Especially in this lovely slider. Lol.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls --> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left control-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right control-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>

 <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>

    <ol class="carousel-linked-nav pagination">
        <li class="active"><a href="#1">&#8226;</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#2">&#8226;</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#3">&#8226;</a>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some modified your html code, I think this code use for you

```
<!-- Start Carousel -->
    <div id="product-detail carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

        <div class="item active">

          <div class="col-md-6">

          <img src="..." alt="...">

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="carousel-text">
              <p class="cat-title pull-right">Mercury</p>
              <p class="cat-icon pull-right">^^^^^</p>
              <p class="caption-text pull-right">Movie buff Tony Chou (Tony Zhou) published in his Vimeo video review with an analysis of the demonstration set of SMS and other text messages in modern cinema.</p>
              <p class="cat-title pull-right">Mercury</p>
              <p class="cat-icon pull-right">^^^^^</p>
              <p class="caption-text pull-right">Movie buff Tony Chou (Tony Zhou) published in his Vimeo video review with an analysis of the demonstration set of SMS and other text messages in modern cinema.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="..." alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="carousel-text">
              <p class="cat-title pull-right">Mercury</p>
              <p class="cat-icon pull-right">^^^^^</p>
              <p class="caption-text pull-right">Movie buff Tony Chou (Tony Zhou) published in his Vimeo video review with an analysis of the demonstration set of SMS and other text messages in modern cinema.</p>              
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left control-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right control-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```